# Missing fields in a joomla sql schema

Tags: joomla

I exported my joomla.sql file through phpMyAdmin and one of the sql statement below is not complete.

CREATE TABLE `XXXX_postinstall_messages` (
  `postinstall_message_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `extension_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '700' COMMENT 'FK to #__extensions',
  `title_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''COMMENT
) ;

Can someone assist to provide the full schema for this particular table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you'll find all joomla tables https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql